# How do I set SelectedValue of Dropdown in Sharepoint Designer?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-designer, selectedvalue, drop-down-menu

I just started using Sharepoint Designer to create forms & screens for end-users.  When I use ASP Dropdownlist or Sharepoint Dropdown controls, I am unable to set the selected-value of the control.

Please help!!!!
Thanks!